# Persisting model property when submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out why property values are not persisting when I return the View with the model.

Index.cshtml

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsWtv)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "Id,ShippingCost")] TestModels model)
{
   //assume the initial value is false. I only want it to switch to true once
   if (!model.IsWtv)
      model.IsWtv = true;

   return View(model);
}
```

Model:

```
public Boolean IsWtv
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

The value for IsWtv is always false when I resubmit the form. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really be following the PRG pattern (POST, Redirect, GET) when dealing with controller action methods (unless this is some type of AJAX request).

With that said, `HtmlHelpers` get the model values from the model state and not the model when you update and return the model. In order to update and return the model, add this line of code in your post method prior to any property modifications:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

or you could set the value of IsWtv in the ModelState itself:

```
//no point in doing any check on the actual variable
//we are always returning true
ModelState["IsWtv"].Value = true;
```

Comment: Hey this worked! As you can see I'm relatively new to MVC so this helps a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NerdinTraining - anytime man - good luck with your learning!